# Rolling LogBack - Failed to create parent directories for: [c:\var...]

Tags: java, logging, logback

I just cloned this project, did the maven update, but I'm not able to run the log. And as I have a problem accessing the database, I need to know what's going on, but I can't create the log

through the log file it should automatically create, or not?

Apparently the system cannot find the file where the log should be.

How could I solve this:

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
     <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
         <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p [%c] - %m%n</pattern>
     </encoder>
 </appender>

 <appender name="fileLogger" 
 class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <Append>true</Append>

    <File>/var/log/app-logs/app.log</File>

    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %p [%c] - %m%n</pattern>
    </encoder>

    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
        <maxIndex>50</maxIndex>
        <FileNamePattern>/var/log/app-logs/app.log.%i</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>

    <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
        <MaxFileSize>20MB</MaxFileSize>
    </triggeringPolicy>
</appender>

<logger name="br.com.teste.searchio" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileLogger"/>
</logger>

<logger name="br.com.teste.searchio.domain.ItemDemanda" level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileLogger"/>
</logger>

<logger name="br.com.teste.searchio.external.presentation.web.struts.FluxoDadosAction" level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileLogger"/>
</logger>

<logger name="br.com.teste.searchio.external.presentation.web.WorkflowCompraTela" level="trace">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileLogger"/>
</logger>

<root level="warn">
    <appender-ref ref="console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileLogger"/>
</root>

<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <!-- reset all previous level configurations of all j.u.l. loggers -->
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
```

```
14:34:03,889 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
14:34:03,890 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
14:34:03,891 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/bwm6/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/localizae_/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
14:34:04,042 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
14:34:04,049 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
14:34:04,077 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [console]
14:34:04,204 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
14:34:04,214 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [fileLogger]
14:34:04,238 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@4f8c8136 - No compression will be used
14:34:04,239 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@4f8c8136 - Large window sizes are not allowed.
14:34:04,239 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy@4f8c8136 - MaxIndex reduced to 21
14:34:04,248 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogger] - Active log file name: /var/log/app-logs/app.log
14:34:04,248 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogger] - File property is set to [/var/log/app-logs/app.log]
14:34:04,253 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogger] - Failed to create parent directories for [C:\var\log\app-logs\app.log]
14:34:04,255 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogger] - openFile(/var/log/app-logs/app.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: \var\log\app-logs\app.log (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: \var\log\app-logs\app.log (O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.recovery.ResilientFileOutputStream.<init>(ResilientFileOutputStream.java:26)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.openFile(FileAppender.java:204)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender.start(FileAppender.java:127)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender.start(RollingFileAppender.java:100)
```

Comment: I am experiencing an similar error.

Comment: @AllPower How did you solve this issue? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem similar to this problem like this.

```
project
  ├ logs       
  | └ test.log      
  └ src
```

application.yml

```
logging: 
file:
name: /logs/test.log
```

In this state I get an error.

application.yml

```
logging: 
file:
name: logs/test.log
```

I deleted the first slash mark to access the folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the base folders, as those won't be created automatically (e.g. `\var\log\app-logs`).
Then, it will start creating the logger file.

Comment: This helps though depending on where the base folders are (and the way you are running the tests), you also need to make sure you can write to them!